# How is Impact Reached calculated?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, user-profile

In my profile it says the impact reached is 214k people. How is this possible? I checked all of my answers and questions and there is no way they total up to 200k+ people reached. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug, but it can be confusing if you aren't familiar with how it works.

It's the `sum of your question views + the sum of the views of a question you have an answer on that meets certain criteria`.

The logic behind the "impact reached" total is explained on [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/342074):

> - **Questions**   * Non-deleted only
> - **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - [Not self-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372469/377214) AND
>   - Also meeting one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - Score at least 5 OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

Comment: Yeah but I checked and it doesn't add up accordingly, all answers that I posted to big viewed questions all have scores of 0

Comment: @DialFrost What was your methodology of checking this? What did you do?

Comment: I looked through every single question and answer I posted

Comment: @DialFrost are you expecting it to be more or less than 214k?

Comment: Way less, maybe around 30k

Comment: @DialFrost [this answer by you](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/397521/163757) should meet the criteria (its a top 3 answer since there are only 3 answers and it has a Score > 0), which this one single answer alone nets you **~177,000** views.

Comment: Hmm strange, I swear I looked through all my answers. Thanks though! I must have missed it